# When not to use a div container in a template?

Tags: vue.js, templates, vue-component

It used to be that the following Vue component was raising an error because "template must have a single child" (or something like that):

```js
<template>
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>world</div>
</template>
```

I discovered by chance that this is not the case anymore and this generates in the final code two separate `<div>` that inherit the behavior of the parent (I discovered that when playing with `display: grid;` and then realized that my component is exploded across the whole screen).

My question is: in which cases is it interesting to have a component whose behaviour is not encapsulated in that component but where the internal pieces are driven by the parent separately?
In other words: which components gain from not having a container `<div>` as the immediate child of the `<template>`?

---

<sup>It may be that the question extends outside of Vue.js but this is the only framework I know</sup>

Comment: The whole wrapping everything inside a div is dirty to me. It reminds me of React. I can't think of a time where having a extra div wrapping everything would be a problem, but why have more DOM elements if you don't need them?

Comment: @bassxzero: I believe this is because otherwise your component does not hold together (which was my case)

Answer (score 0):

Vue3 started to support multi-root components. They have some limitations but it's up to you to decide whether to use use them, for example you can make a basic page layout:

Layout.vue

```
<template>
<header>
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <!-- other common header elements -->
  <slot name="header"></slot>
</header>
<main>
  <nav>...</nav>
  <slot></slot>
</main>
<footer>
  <!-- common footer elements -->
  <slot name="footer"></slot>
</footer>
</template>
<style scoped>
/* style your header, main, footer here */
</style>
```

Comment: I understand that but in this case it wouldn't change anything to enclose all of these elements in an encompassing `<div>`. I am wondering which problem this multi-root approach solves.

Comment: @WoJ sometimes you just don't want a wrapping container...